# How do I convert a date in dd/mm/yyyy format to mm/dd/yyyy in Excel sheet

Tags: datetime, excel-2010

I have the following dates:

`1/12/2011,
04/12/2011`

as dd/mm/yyyy format so I need to convert them to mm/dd/yyyy in order to store those values in SQL Server database. How to convert the value to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: If you are putting them in to SQL Server as strings, use YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 0):

select the cells that you wish to change and go to 
   tab 
In the Category window, click on  
And see if you can find something that you like in the Type window, 
Then click OK.

Otherwise, you can click on Custom in the Category window and enter your own 
format in the Type window, and then OK.